# xslproc , how to apply-templates to local xml file using document()

Tags: xml, xslt, import

I have the following situation: 3 XML files from the knime.org workbench.

```
$ find -type f
./workflow.knime
./File Reader (#1)/settings.xml
./CSV Writer (#2)/settings.xml
```

yes: the filenames contain spaces and hashes...

here is a snapshot of the 3 files:

```
$ xmllint --format  ./workflow.knime
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://www.knime.org/2008/09/XMLConfig">
  <config key="nodes">
    <config key="node_1">
      <entry key="node_settings_file" type="xstring" value="File Reader (#1)/settings.xml"/>
    </config>
    <config key="node_2">
      <entry key="node_settings_file" type="xstring" value="CSV Writer (#2)/settings.xml"/>
    </config>
  </config>
</config>


$ xmllint --format File\ Reader\ \(#1\)/settings.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://www.knime.org/2008/09/XMLConfig">
  <config key="filestores">
    <entry key="file_store_id" type="xstring" value="b23a87fd-a3ff-430b-8c12-fe9186e30004"/>
  </config>
</config>


$  xmllint --format CSV\ Writer\ \(#2\)/settings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://www.knime.org/2008/09/XMLConfig">
  <config key="filestores">
    <entry key="file_store_id" type="xstring" value="ac3dde81-7363-4191-8f4c-3cba026391df"/>
  </config>
</config>
```

I'd like to run xsltproc with `document` to digest the 3 files. I tried the following **xslt** stylesheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
        xmlns:k="http://www.knime.org/2008/09/XMLConfig"
        version='1.0'
        >

<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="k:config/k:config[@key='nodes']/k:config" mode="node"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="k:config" mode="node">
<xsl:variable name="f1" select="k:entry[@key='node_settings_file']/@value"/>
<xsl:message>reading <xsl:value-of select="$f1"/></xsl:message>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document($f1)/*" mode="extdoc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="extdoc">
<xsl:text>IN EXTERNAL DOC</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="extdoc"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but no "IN EXTERNAL DOC" is displayed.

```
$ xsltproc jeter.xsl workflow.knime
reading File Reader (#1)/settings.xml
reading CSV Writer (#2)/settings.xml

$ xsltproc --verbose jeter.xsl workflow.knime
(...)
xsltValueOf: select $f1
Lookup variable 'f1'
xsltCopyTextString: copy text CSV Writer (#2)/settings.xml
xsltValueOf: result 'CSV Writer (#2)/settings.xml'
reading CSV Writer (#2)/settings.xml
xsltApplyTemplates: node: 'config'
xsltApplyTemplates: select document($f1)/*
Lookup variable 'f1'
xsltApplyTemplates: select didn't evaluate to a node list
freeing transformation dictionary
```

How should I use `document()` ?

**FIXED**: it works when using  str:encode-uri

```
<xsl:variable name="f1" select="k:entry[@key='node_settings_file']/@value"/>
<xsl:variable name="f2" select="str:encode-uri($f1,'UTF-8')"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document($f2)/*" mode="extdoc"/>
```

Comment: The `document` function expects a URI (relative or absolute), not a native path, so it may be that the spaces and parentheses need to be escaped as `%NN`

Comment: Thank you @IanRoberts it works ! can you pelase move your comment to an answer so I can validate it ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document` function expects its parameter to be a *URI reference* rather than a native file path.  You will need to encode the spaces, parentheses and hash characters as `%NN` escapes in order to produce a valid URI.